# Swift enum get an associated value without passing through a cases

Tags: swift, enums

Is there an easy way without passing from a whole switch to get an associated value? I've already read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263539/accessing-an-enumeration-association-value-in-swift) and it seems that (as 2.0 beta) the only solution is create a method that extract it, but maybe in latest version the SWIFT team has improved this functionality.

 
I'm trying to do something like that:

```
    switch additionalInfo {
    case _ (let instrumentAddData):
        print("\(instrumentAddData)")
    default:
        print("Default")
```

Comment: I think that the linked-to Q&A is what you are looking for. Otherwise let me know and I'll reopen the question.

Comment: Hello @MartinR thank you, but is not the same. In the answer provided you still need to know the enumeration case, as you can see in my snippet I'd like to just unwrap the associated value without checking a specific case.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: Ok :( thank you anyway