# Why does JSON Decoder return nil when program was working fine before with no changes?

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, jsondecoder

Hello wonderful people of the internet, I am confused as to why my program does not work. It was working fine and then suddenly it started returning nil from the JSON decoder. Any thoughts on why this might be? Thank you for your help and have a wonderful day!

```
import SwiftUI

struct CommentFeedView: View {
    @State var comments = [Comment]()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(comments) { comment in
                // UI Code goes here
                }
                // More UI Code goes here
            }
            .onAppear {
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { timer in
                    getComments()
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Comments")
        }
    }
    func getComments() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.reddit.com/r/GoForGold/comments.json?limit=25")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let decodedComments = try? JSONDecoder().decode(CommentListing.self, from: data) { //decodedComments is nil
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let commentObjectsWrapper = decodedComments.data!
                        let commentObjects = commentObjectsWrapper.children
                        for commentObject in commentObjects {
                            self.comments.append(commentObject.data!)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                print("Request failed")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than `try?`ing aka ignoring any error **catch** and `print` it. By the way `"Request failed"` will never be reached. Either `data` or `error` is valid, there is no third state.

Comment: I agree, try? for decoding external data is a bad practice. I think you should check if `error` is not nil before checking `data` but maybe that is more of a personal preference.

Comment: Thank you both! I did just that and now I get an error that says "Expected to decode Bool but found a number instead." Time for a new stack overflow question I guess lol

Comment: Read the error message carefully. It tells you exactly what's wrong and even where. Obviously the API sends an `Int` instead of a `Bool` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for checking back in! I changed my struct to have the edited value become an int instead of a bool and got this error "Expected to decode Int but found a number instead." Is an Int not a number?!

Comment: Take a look at the JSON string to figure out the actual type.

Comment: Turns out if a comment has been edited, Reddit changes the type from a bool to an int. I found another Stack Overflow thread that I think will help me take it from here. [The thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935705/using-codable-with-value-that-is-sometimes-an-int-and-other-times-a-string)