# Forgiving decoding of types in Swift

Tags: json, swift, decoding

I am currently working on an app that has a lot of legacy data from the backend. This means types are very unreliable. I can get a boolean like these examples `"canJump": "1"` `"canJump": 0` `"canJump": "true"` `"canJump": false`. So I have been pondering about good ways to handle decoding this. I would like to avoid:

```swift
if let bool = try? container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .jump) {
  self.canJump = bool
}

if let boolAsString = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .jump) {
  if boolAsString == "true" || boolAsString == "false" {
    self.canJump = Bool(boolAsString)
  }
}
```

etc. in every single custom decoder. So I tried an extension:

```swift
extension KeyedDecodingContainer {    
    func decodeWithUnknownTypes(_ type: Bool.Type, forKey key: KeyedDecodingContainer<K>.Key) throws -> Bool? {
        do {
            return try decode(Bool.self, forKey: key)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {}
        
        do {
            let string = try decode(String.self, forKey: key)
            return Bool(string.lowercased())
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {}
        
        do {
            let int = try decode(Int.self, forKey: key)
            if int == 1 {
                return true
            }
            if int == 0 {
                return false
            }
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```

(not entirely finished). The above almost does the trick, but it still leaves me having to implement custom decoders in almost all my backend calls. I would love it if someone has an idea of how I could write it, so I can simply use a Decodable struct, and it would automagically accept 1 as a Bool. Can I maybe override the `decode` method of KeyedDecodingContainer and still get the original function as a "first try"?

Comment: Use a property wrapper

Comment: I would like to see, how you would implement it with a property wrapper? Sadly are we still supporting iOS 12 but soon to be deprecated so maybe in a later release I could use your suggestion.

Comment: Have a look at what they do in this library: https://github.com/GottaGetSwifty/CodableWrappers

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60246989/1974224 - it applies to decoding strings, but support for bools can be easily added.

Comment: @Alexander, thank you - pretty cool library I will see if we can use later or maybe do some of the same.

Comment: @Cristik very true, I also considered doing a wrapper type, but I still think it's sub optimal in my case as I would basically need it everywhere.

Comment: @MathiasEgekvist then you might need a custom decoder, which can also translate to lots of code to replace `JSONDecoder`.