# Crash when casting from Result<T> to unrelated type T always fails

Tags: ios, swift, casting, crash

I am getting a crash when I cast my singleResult (of Type `Result<FAQResult>`) to a `FAQResult`

```
fileprivate var fAQS = [FAQ]()

 when(resolved: task).then { (result) -> Void in
       let singleResult:Result<FAQResult> = result.first!     
       let whereItCrashes = singleResult as! FAQResult
       self.fAQS =  whereItCrashes.result!
    }
```

> Cast from Result<FAQResult> to unrelated type FAQResult always fails

The code under is from a core-promise pod used in the project. All it does it give me back a .boolValue, but I need to convert it from a 
Results to a FAQResult.

```
    public enum Result<T> {
    /// Fulfillment
    case fulfilled(T)
    /// Rejection
    case rejected(Error)

    init(_ resolution: Resolution<T>) {
        switch resolution {
        case .fulfilled(let value):
            self = .fulfilled(value)
        case .rejected(let error, _):
            self = .rejected(error)
        }
    }

    /**
     - Returns: `true` if the result is `fulfilled` or `false` if it is `rejected`.
     */
    public var boolValue: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .fulfilled:
            return true
        case .rejected:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Any solutions on how to let it cast correctly?

Comment: The error message is quite clear, you cant cast Result<FAQResult> to FAQResult, they are different thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263539/accessing-an-enumeration-association-value-in-swift this post tells you how to get the associated value from enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add new computed property `value` to `Result<T>` like this:

```
/**
 - Returns: actual fulfilled `value` if the result is `fulfilled` or `nil` if it is `rejected`.
*/
public var value: T? {
    switch self {
    case .fulfilled(let value):
        return value
    case .rejected:
        return nil
    }
}
```

And then `singleResult.value` will return you `FAQResult`.