# Accessing a non raw type enumerations case values?

Tags: swift, wrapper, enumeration

So I have an enumeration defined as the following:

```
enum CardPosition {
    case top(CGFloat) 
    case middle(CGFloat)
    case bottom(CGFloat) 
}
```

I have a variable of type CardPosition that is defined as:

```
@State private var position: CardPosition = CardPosition.bottom(UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 100)
```

How do I access the value of the CardPosition? In this case, I'm trying to access the UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 100 value from the enumeration. I tried accessing it with

```
self.position.rawValue
```

but unfortunately this doesn't work. Anyone know how I can access the CGFloat value of position?

Comment: `Swift Enum + Associated Values` These are the keywords you were missing. Read https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148 for instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing an Enumeration association value in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263539/accessing-an-enumeration-association-value-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a switch here:

```
switch position {
case .top(let f):
    // use f
case .middle(let f):
    // use f
case .bottom(let f):
    // use f
}
```

If you want it as an *expression*, you can do something like:

```
// you can assign the below to a variable or whatever
// let value =
{ () -> CGFloat in
    switch position {
    case .top(let f):
        return f
    case .middle(let f):
        return f
    case .bottom(let f):
        return f
    }
}()
```

However, I think the best solution is to redesign your types. It seems like there will always be a `CGFloat` associated with every case of your enum. Why not use a struct composing a simple enum and a `CGFloat`?

```
enum RelativeCardPosition {
    case top
    case middle
    case bottom
}

struct CardPosition {
    let relativeCardPosition: RelativeCardPosition
    let offset: CGFloat
    
    static func top(_ offset: CGFloat) -> CardPosition {
        CardPosition(relativeCardPosition: .top, offset: offset)
    }
    
    static func middle(_ offset: CGFloat) -> CardPosition {
        CardPosition(relativeCardPosition: .middle, offset: offset)
    }
    
    static func bottom(_ offset: CGFloat) -> CardPosition {
        CardPosition(relativeCardPosition: .bottom, offset: offset)
    }
}
```

Then you can easily access the number via `position.offset`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a *Computed Property* `position` inside the `enum CardPosition` and `return` the associated value with each `case`, i.e.

```
enum CardPosition {
    case top(CGFloat)
    case middle(CGFloat)
    case bottom(CGFloat)
    
    var position: CGFloat {
        switch self {
        case .top(let pos), .middle(let pos), .bottom(let pos):
            return pos
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it should have been downvoted. Maybe [Tim lost his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/302707). Don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the associated value for your `.bottom` variable you use `if let case` syntax

```
var position: CardPosition = CardPosition.bottom(UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 100.0)

if case let CardPosition.bottom(positionValue) = position {
    print(positionValue)
}
```

This will give you only a value for `.bottom` and not for any of the other enum cases.