# Trying build a func for multiply which accept any type numbers to work

Tags: swift

I want to build a func which can take CGFloat, Double or Int as Input and return the multiply answer depending on input values types, like this code:

**Update:** I noticed that my explaining was not sharp enough,sorry, so I am explaining here, I do not want my return type be fixed to Double or Int or CGFloat, my return type is dynamic and depend on lhs and rhs! If one of those input is type CGFloat, then return type would be definitely CGFloat, but if function was not able detect any CGFloat type, then it will try the same thing for Double, and At least for Int, this function will return nil for any other type than Int, Double or CGFloat.

I could made mistakes with choosing **Numeric** I wanted function be open to accept any kind of number types like Int, Double, CGFloat, And the reason I chose T and U it was this: lhs could be Int and rhs could be Double or CGFloat. or opposite.

The user of function could be able for example load Int to lhs, and CGFloat to rhs and get answer in CGFloat type or:
The user of function could be able for example load Double to lhs, and Int to rhs and get answer in Double type.

```
    func advancedMultiply<T: Numeric, U: Numeric> (lhs: T, rhs: U) -> Numeric? {


    if (type(of: lhs) == CGFloat.self) || (type(of: rhs) == CGFloat.self) {

        return CGFloat(lhs)*CGFloat(rhs)

    }
    else if (type(of: lhs) == Double.self) || (type(of: rhs) == Double.self) {
        
        return Double(lhs)*Double(rhs)

    }
    else if (type(of: lhs) == Int.self) && (type(of: rhs) == Int.self) {
        
        return lhs*rhs
        
    }
    else {
        
        return nil
        
    }

}
```

I tried my best to make it working, but it has errors to compile, i need help to find the right way.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you could make this function work, what would you use it for?

Comment: updated made in up

Comment: What you are saying is not possible with just one function in Swift.

Comment: ok do it in several function I chain them together

Comment: Out of curiosity: if `lhs` is `Int` and `rhs` is `Double` what should be returned?

Comment: Int + Double -> Double, Int + CGFloat -> CGFloat, Double + CGFloat -> CGFloat, Int + Int -> Int

Comment: It is almost Swift inference scenario in return type

Comment: But the inference only works when the return type is known. Here you can have different return types. As far as I understand, what you want is just not possible in Swift. If you want to multiply different types you can create custom operators like `func * (lhs: CGFloat, rhs: Double) -> CGFloat { lhs * CGFloat(rhs) }`. Alternatively, you can try creating an enum as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24267183/8697793

Answer (score -1):

First, it's `BinaryInteger`, not `Numeric`

Second, `T` and `U` conform to the same Protocol does not mean they will be the same type. So that, your return value is incorrect. Try a different value, such as: Bool, String, Int,...

You can find more information [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-fix-the-error-protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associated-type-requirements)

Comment: 1. Replace `Numeric` with `BinaryInteger`

2. Replace return value with different type (Bool, String,...)

3. Replace `lhs*rhs` to `Int(lhs)*Int(rhs)`

It should work :)

Comment: BinaryInteger?! doesn't make sense! my return type is dynamic, it could be Int, Double, CGFloat or nil, why you say I must replace Numeric with BinaryInteger? you are limiting answer type to Int which does not match the question condition